# how to set radio button checked in edit mode in MVC razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new in MVC razor. I am trying to edit the web page. In which I have two radio buttons. I am successful in save data for radio button values. But when I trying to edit that value I am not able to select that radio button for which data is saved. 
I have enum for Gender

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

My create code is :-

```
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, (int)Gender.Male) Male
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, (int)Gender.Female) Female
</div>
```

Edit code is like

```
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender)
</div>
<div>
   @if (Model.gender == (int)Gender.Male)
   {
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "Male", new { @checked = true })
   @Html.Label("Male")
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "Female")
   @Html.Label("Female")
   }
   else
   {
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "Male")
   @Html.Label("Male")
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "Female", new { @checked = true })
   @Html.Label("Female")
   }
</div>
```

Comment: i'm amused why are you making code complex . i dont like the idea of enum on first look for Gender . i suggest you to have look into model binding approach ex: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.gender)` . this model binding serves you bi-directional of saving n editing

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have written like

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "Male", new { @checked = true }) and
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "Female", new { @checked = true })
```

Here you have taken gender as a `Enum` type and you have written the value for the radio button as a `string` type- change "Male" to 0 and "Female" to 1.

Comment: Both of the radio buttons will have `checked="true"`

Comment: He wasn't suggesting that code, he was highlighting what the OP had written. The advice should be applied to the original code

Answer (score 14):

Don't do this at the view level. Just set the default value to the property in your view model's constructor. Clean and simple. In your post-backs, your selected value will automatically populate the correct selection.

For example

```
public class MyViewModel
{
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Gender = "Male";
        }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
 <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Gender, "Male")Male</label></td>
 <td><label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Gender, "Female")Female</label></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: It is not getting reflected in UI.

Comment: Which version are you using? I think I must have run this with MVC 3. Pretty sure it worked when I tested it. Also, there was a typo in my closing </td> tag. I just fixed it, so if you had copy-pasted my answer, please try again.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code for get value of checked radio button and set radio button checked according to it's value in edit form:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        CommonServiceReference.tbl_user user = new CommonServiceReference.tbl_user();
        user.user_gender = collection["rdbtnGender"];
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    CommonServiceReference.ViewUserGroup user = clientObj.getUserById(id);
    ViewBag.UserObj = user;
    return View();
}
```

**VIEW:**

Create:

```
<input type="radio" id="rdbtnGender1" name="rdbtnGender" value="Male" required>
<label for="rdbtnGender1">MALE</label>
<input type="radio" id="rdbtnGender2" name="rdbtnGender" value="Female" required>
<label  for="rdbtnGender2">FEMALE</label>
```

Edit:

```
<input type="radio" id="rdbtnGender1" name="rdbtnGender" value="Male" @(ViewBag.UserObj.user_gender == "Male" ? "checked='true'" : "") required>
<label for="rdbtnGender1">MALE</label>

<input type="radio" id="rdbtnGender2" name="rdbtnGender" value="Female" @(ViewBag.UserObj.user_gender == "Female" ? "checked='true'" : "") required>
<label for="rdbtnGender2">FEMALE</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it and works both for create and edit:

```
//How to do it with enums
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, (int)Gender.Male) Male
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, (int)Gender.Female) Female
</div>

//And with Booleans
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsMale, true) Male
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsMale, false) Female
</div>
```

the provided values (true and false) are the values that the engine will render as the values for the html  element  i.e.:

```
<input id="IsMale" type="radio" name="IsMale" value="True">
<input id="IsMale" type="radio" name="IsMale" value="False">
```

And the checked property is dependent on the Model.IsMale value.

Razor engine seems to internally match the set radio button value to your model value, if a proper from and to string convert exists for it.
So there is no need to add it as an html attribute in the helper method.

Comment: trying to figure out how this works in "edit" mode? You're hard-coding the values, but rigging it with the same "isMale" boolean...

Comment: @RobWashington, the provided values (true and false) are the values that the engine will render as the values for the html <input> element  i.e.:

<input id="IsMale" type="radio" name="IsMale" value="True">
<input id="IsMale" type="radio" name="IsMale" value="False">

And the checked property is dependent on the Model.IsMale value.

Comment: @Nikolay...thanks for the clarification. I understand that part. I guess I was thinking ahead a bit and saw that this solution will only work when you have 2 radio options that are either true or false. But when you have multiple radio options (which is not what the OP required) this would be bad. But I get your solution now.

Comment: @RobWashington, there would be absolutely no problem in creating an Enum with more than two values. Mapping it properly as shown above to the respective number of radio buttons will work equally as well. The Boolean example was to make the mapping a bit clearer, cheers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add checked to both of your radio button. And then show/hide your desired one on document ready.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="mt-radio-inline" style="padding-left:15px;">
        <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">
            Full Edition
            <input type="radio" value="@((int)SelectEditionTypeEnum.FullEdition)" asp-for="SelectEditionType" checked>
            <span></span>
        </label>
        <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">
            Select Modules
            <input type="radio" value="@((int)SelectEditionTypeEnum.CustomEdition)" asp-for="SelectEditionType" checked>
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To set radio button checked in edit mode in MVC razor view, please trying as follow:

```
<div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11">
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Role, "1", Model.Role == 1 ? "checked" : string.Empty) 
     <span>Admin</span>
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Role, "0", Model.Role == 0 ? "checked" : string.Empty)
     <span>User</span>
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Role)
</div>
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `@checked = "checked"` attribute did not work because I was loading default values from the model, which were not equal with the RadioButton value.
Once I changed the loaded values from the model to be equal to the radiobutton value, the button was checked.

For example this will make the radiobutton to be checked by default:

In the model:

```
response.data = "data"
```

In the view:

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.data, "data",new  {@class="form-check-input"})
 <label class="form-check-label">Data (default)</label>
```